# Two interactive windows in Gnuplot with wxt terminal

Tags: gnuplot

I often use the `wxt` terminal of Gnuplot to do some quick data inspection. I like the interactivity, such that I can easily gain control and zoom/move et cetera.

Suppose I have to following script

```
set terminal wxt 0 persist
plot x

set terminal wxt 1 persist
plot x**2
```

Now, on window 1 I have the interactive control. However, on window 0 this interactive control is lost.

My question is: How can I obtain interactive control on window 0?

I am using `gnuplot 4.6.2`. I've seen [gnuplot multiple graphs are not interactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307204/gnuplot-multiple-graphs-are-not-interactive) but the question in about `x11` terminal, and the answers consist of opening multiple instance of `gnuplot`, which seems unnecessary to me.

Comment: While I was looking into this, I realized that you can *regain* control of your first window, by repeating the `set term wxt 0 persist` command. **However**, as soon as you do something in the terminal (e.g. activate the grid lines), the graph changes to your most recent plot (in this case `x**2`). Until now, this is just an observation. I'll share if I dig out something useful.

Comment: @Schorsch Hmm, that is interesting. Realize that I do not use any `gnuplot` command line (just `gnuplot plot.gnu`), such that I cannot even type `set term wxt 0 persist`.

Comment: @Schorsch I also observe that, while taking control over `window 0`, on zoom-in it will plot the function that I plotted in `window 1`

Comment: You cannot change back, I thinks this is similar to `set multiplot layout 1,2; plot x; plot x**2; unset multiplot` and then changing the window size -> only the last plot remains.

Comment: @Christoph So this should be a feature request?

Comment: I think so, but I have no idea if this is feasible. I had a look at the feature request [#344 zoom in multiplot ](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/344/). There, Ethan say, that qt and wxt actually have a local copy of the plotted data. However, I don't know if this also applies to different windows and how much work that would be.

Comment: @Christoph So probably it will be easier to change my workflow a bit?

Comment: Yes, I guess, this will be easier.

Comment: @Christoph I just took a look at this post and all that cross my mind in this point is that software is supposed to adapt to the human needs, not backwards. I would like to submit the feature request, I am needing to be able to zoom in and out from multiple windows right now. Can you tell me how to submit the feature request?

Comment: @Hans Indeed, software is supposed to adapt. But if the whole design of the respective software isn't apt to handle that requirements, it may not be adapted... You can submit a feature request at https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/

Answer (score 1):

I believe have found a workaround for this problem.
But not sure if this works for all cases.

My solution sounds like obvious.
I created three files: `configs.plt`, `wxt1.plt`, and `wxt2.plt`.

The `configs.plt` file contains:

```c
set style line 1 lc "#e41a1c"
set style line 2 lc "#377eb8"
```

The `wxt1.plt` file contains:

```c
set terminal wxt title "plot sin"
load "configs.plt"
plot sin(x) w l ls 1
```

The `wxt2.plt` file contains:

```c
set terminal wxt title "plot cos"
load "configs.plt"
plot cos(x) w l ls 2
```

[image: screen capture]

The only boring thing is run two instead one file.

Comment: in my case i got an error `line 0: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list` using `set terminal wxt `. I had to understand i needed to list the known terminals `gnuplot -p -e "set terminal"` then replace the value `wxt` with whatever i need, currently i wanted `qt`. It worked !