# How to keep previous plots and windows in Gnuplot?

Tags: plot, terminal, gnuplot

I have some problems of using gnuplot. I just begin with it.

(1)What is the command for keeping the previous plot when I plot new data? Do I have to plot the old data and the new data at the same time?

(2)What is the command for open a new window while keep the old ones? Do I have to set the window's id by using, e.g.,
    set terminal wxt 3
, before each plot?

Can anyone give me some help or some good references?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already wrote the answers of your questions.

1.: You can use the replot command:

```
plot sin(x)
replot cos(x)
```

but this just expands to

```
plot sin(x), cos(x)
```

So, it replots all data and does not just add the cos(x).

2.: Yes, you can also switch between the windows to update the plots. But note that settings like ranges and labels are not stored per window / plot, but globally. If they are different for different plots, you have to change them every time.

You may also have a look at "set multiplot" to put several plots on one window / picture. But it is not so nice for interactive plotting, as you will notice.
Also, output terminals supporting multiple pages like pdfcairo will add a new page for each plot.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, to plot several data set you would use

```
plot 'data1.dat', 'data2.dat'
```

You could also use `replot` to add one of the data sets later

```
plot 'data1.dat'
...
replot 'data2.dat'
```

To open a new window, you must use the window's id like with `set terminal wxt 2`. The old windows stay open, but you cannot interact with them anymore (zooming, scrolling etc.). See also the discussion to the quesiton [Two interactive windows in Gnuplot with wxt terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24037770/2604213).